# Cannot return enum data type?

Tags: enum

I have the below enums:

```json
    // ENUMS
    enum StateType {
        ItemAvailable,
        OfferPlaced,
        Accepted
    }
```

And initialized the below variable `State` with type `StateType`:

```json
    StateType State;
```

Finally, I have a getter to return the current state:

```json
    function getState() view public returns (StateType) {
        return State;
    }
```

However after deploying the contract, Remix converts the return value of `State` to a `uint8` instead of the expected `State` variable. How can I get a return value of `ItemAvailable`, `OfferPlaced`, or `Accepted`?

Comment: I think the problem is that enum aren't part of the contract abi. Similarly structs are returned as a tuple and they don't create a struct type. It is a nice feature, but I haven't seen it implemented.